# No intel thunderbolt support in 14.04.02

Tags: 14.04, intel, thunderbolt

I have a new Dell m3800 and cannot get thunderbolt working in Ubuntu.  I have upgraded the installation:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

And I am running the 3.16 kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux eliasDell 3.16.0-31-generic #41~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 11 19:30:13 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am trying to test with a thunderbolt ethernet adapter.  It doesn't work either hotplugging or plugged in before boot.  I also have an Apple Thunderbolt monitor available for testing.  Note that I have also put a dual-boot installation of Win8.1 on this system, and all of the thunderbolt listed above works (hotplugging) in windows.  So I am confident the hardware is good and this is an issue with Ubuntu.

My understanding was that thunderbolt support was supposed to be included in the 14.04.2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've read that people needed to update the kernel to 3.17 for hotplug support. You should try upgrading the kernel to mainline.

I need an upgrade to my current laptop and this device looks perfect, but if I can't use it with my thunderbolt monitor, then I have to sell it and get a display port monitor instead :(

I'm surprised the monitor doesn't work out of the box. Do normal DP monitors work correctly in ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: I will try and upgrade the kernel to mainline. The thunderbolt monitor works in windows on this laptop. I tested that for sanity.

Comment: @Frac did you eventually get this working?

Comment: I have the same computer an m3800 laptop. This works for 3.18 but only for monitor support, nothing connected into the monitor works.  It is also flakey at best with constant graphics glitches and issues.

Comment: I did get this working.  As i recall the solution was actually in the bios to allow the thunderbolt unrestricted operation.  In Windows, each thunderbolt device was asking for permission and then worked once granted. There was no corresponf

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my external monitor working after upgrading to kernel 3.19:

`sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid`